# Matlab Shared C/C++ lib in VS10/12 throws a lot exceptions

Tags: c++, matlab, exception, shared-libraries

i got a run time problem with my **matlab c/c++ shared lib**. The library exports and the application is **compiled and linked correctly**. But on run-time the script seems to have a lot of errors. 
There is no error displayed in the console window (displaying the matlab output) of my application. But the **debugger shows a lot of uncaught exceptions** on the run. But script seems to run through and the application terminates correctly.

Some things to know:

- Building on Win8 Pro x64
- Visual Studio 2012 (Project settings are VS 2010, which is installed correctly)
- Matlab R2012b (32Bit) (64Bit version is also installed, but not used here, as far as i know)
- MCR R2012b win32/64 is installed
- Compiler used in Matlab Compiler is the VS2010 one (compiling with GUI-compiler)

Well, here is the m-file i am exporting to a shared lib:

```
% Create video input object. 
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'YUY2_320x240')

% Set video input object properties for this application.
set(vid,'TriggerRepeat',Inf);
vid.FrameGrabInterval = 3;

% Set value of a video source object property.
vid_src = getselectedsource(vid);
set(vid_src,'Tag','motion detection setup');
set(vid,'ReturnedColorSpace','rgb');

% Create a figure window.
figure; 
% wiener filter neighbourhood
wienerFilter = [5 5];
% Start acquiring frames.
start(vid)

% Calculate difference image and display it.
while(vid.FramesAcquired<=200) % Stop after 200 frames
    data = getdata(vid,2);

    first_img = wiener2(rgb2gray(data(:,:,:,1)), wienerFilter);
    second_img = wiener2(rgb2gray(data(:,:,:,2)), wienerFilter);

    bw_img = im2bw(first_img);

    diff_im = imabsdiff(first_img,second_img);

    subplot(1,3,1), imshow(first_img);
    subplot(1,3,2), imshow(second_img);
    subplot(1,3,3), imshow(diff_im);

end

stop(vid)

delete(vid)
close(gcf)
```

If you have a webcam on your computer the script should run without errors!

Now the main C++ file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MatlabCompilerSample.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "MatlabCompilerSample.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    /* Call the MCR and library initialization functions */
    if( !mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0) )
    {
        const char* message = mclGetLastErrorMessage();
        printf_s(message);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize the application.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!MatlabCompilerSampleInitialize())
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not initialize the library.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Call the implementation function */
    WebcamSample();

    /* Call the library termination function */
    MatlabCompilerSampleTerminate();

    mclTerminateApplication();
    return 0;
}
```

Looks good until now? After loading a bunch of dlls the mess begins. 
Look at the exceptions and crap thrown:

```
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfcloc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_49768ef57548175e\MFC90DEU.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x003DF4A0.
SetThrowSegvLongjmpSEHFilter(): filter function installed
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003D6210.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003D5A4C.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003D6210.
```

Well thats goes on a while and then:

```
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::thread_interrupted at memory location 0x060EFD98.
The thread 0x2478 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003DE000.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003DD83C.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003DE000.
```

Thats not all...

```
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003DD0B4.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003DDEA0.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::thread_interrupted at memory location 0x061EF980.
The thread 0x282c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003DE328.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003DDB64.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003DE328.
```

...

```
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError at memory location 0x003DE1C8.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::thread_interrupted at memory location 0x061EFC14.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::thread_interrupted at memory location 0x060EFDEC.
The thread 0x32a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x350c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::thread_interrupted at memory location 0x060EFC1C.
The thread 0xfd8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::thread_interrupted at memory location 0x05FEFC7C.
The thread 0x2144 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\sys\java\jre\win32\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr71.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x0771F404.
SetThrowSegvLongjmpSEHFilter(): filter function installed
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\NapiNSP.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\pnrpnsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nlaapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winrnr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\tiptsf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\sys\java\jre\win32\jre\bin\verify.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\sys\java\jre\win32\jre\bin\java.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\sys\java\jre\win32\jre\bin\hpi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\sys\java\jre\win32\jre\bin\zip.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\sys\java\jre\win32\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\sys\java\jre\win32\jre\bin\awt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\bin\win32\nativejmi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\bin\win32\nativeservices.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\bin\win32\nativejava.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\sys\java\jre\win32\jre\bin\net.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\sys\java\jre\win32\jre\bin\nio.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x0771F284.
SetThrowSegvLongjmpSEHFilter(): filter function installed
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 (KernelBase.dll) in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: 0x000006BA: Der RPC-Server ist nicht verfügbar.
The thread 0x37b0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::AES_PHM_Decryption::InvalidCiphertextOrKey at memory location 0x0771C1B8.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::AES_PHM_Decryption::InvalidCiphertextOrKey at memory location 0x0771C988.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x077189E7.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x0771B82C.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x07717E57.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x0771ACA0.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\bin\win32\libmwbuiltins.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\bin\win32\mlint.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x07717E57.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x0771ACA0.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\bin\win32\libmwmathelem.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\bin\win32\libmwmathxps.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: varflowFailedException at memory location 0x0771BCD7.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: varflowFailedException at memory location 0x0771BD82.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\bin\win32\hgbuiltins.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\bin\win32\nativemvm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'N:\Programme\MATLAB\2012b (32Bit)\bin\win32\nativehg.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::AES_PHM_Decryption::InvalidCiphertextOrKey at memory location 0x07716AC0.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x07714C0F.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x07717A5C.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::AES_PHM_Decryption::InvalidCiphertextOrKey at memory location 0x07717628.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x0771367F.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedExceptionNoUCB at memory location 0x077137EC.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x07715940.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x077162C7.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: tfFailedException at memory location 0x07719110.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: varflowFailedException at memory location 0x07719773.
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: varflowFailedException at memory location 0x077197EE.
```

The whole file is 6000 lines...i'll post it if necessary!
Here it stops after all:

```
First-chance exception at 0x76AB4B32 (KernelBase.dll) in MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe: 0xA1A01DB2 (parameters: 0x1FD09FE6, 0x1FD08200, 0x00000000).
The program '[3324] MatlabCompilerCPPExample.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**I would be glad for every hint, thanks in advance!**

Comment: Many of those messages seem related to the fact that there are no debugger symbols defined for the DLL. It crashes somewhere, tries to go into debug mode and fails.

Comment: Also. Have you tried compiling simple 'hello world' type of program? Is your compiler pipeline usually running without error? One of my favorite tacts here is to remore/add lines to the matlab script and see when exactly it fails.

Answer (score 2):

These are all first chance exceptions and doesnt mean there is problem. I've seen them a lot in my previous job and Matlab have a tendecy to produce a lot of exception which neither was a real problem.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx

> Does a first chance exception mean there is a problem in my code?
>   First chance exception messages most often do not mean there is a problem in the code. For applications / components which handle exceptions gracefully, first chance exception messages let the developer know that an exceptional situation was encountered and was handled.

Comment: The real problem is that MATLAB does indeed throw a _lot_ of exceptions, both during initialization and during execution. They are evidently handled internally but it seems to me that this reveals that their programming model includes the anti-patterns of using exceptions instead of other more appropriate flow-control methods and also swallowing potentially valid exceptions (when I am debugging a MATLAB-based application I will often find the debugger stops with AccessViolation exception reading some near-zero memory location.)